# Select Northings from a 1 Line String

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have the following string;

```
Start: 738392E, 6726376N
```

I extracted `738392` ok using `(?<=.art\:\s)([0-9A-Z]*)`. This gave me a one group match allowing me to extract it as a column value

[image].

I want to extract `6726376` the same way. Have only one group appear because I am parsing that to a column value.

Not sure why is `(?=(art\:\s\s*))(?=[,])*(.*[0-9]*)` giving me the entire line after S.

[image]

Helping me get it right with an explanation will go along way.

Comment: Your first lookahead will match the `art:` from St**art**. The second lookahead doesn't match anything but it's irrelevant because you have the `*` quantifier. So you're matching *from* where the first lookahead tested positive until the end of the line with `(.*[0-9]*)`

Answer (score 4):

Because you used positive lookaheads. Those just make some assertions, but don't "move the head along".

`(?=(art\:\s\s*))`  makes sure you're before "art: ...". The next thing is another positive lookahead that you quantify with a star to make it optional. Finally you match anything, so you get the rest of the line in your capture group.

I propose a simpler regex:

```
(?<=(art\:\s))(\d+)\D+(\d+)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/0n922N/1)

First we make a positive lookback that makes sure we're *after* "art: ", then we match two numbers, seperated by non-numbers.

Comment: AHA... Thanks, I just made it by   (?=(art\:\s\s*))(?=[,])*(.*[0-9]*)(........)  which wasn't as elegant

Comment: Always be careful with stars, especially with `.*`, because a) they can match nothing, because they're optional, and b) they can eat the rest of your input.

Comment: What if all I wanted is a regex to match the relevant text as group 1 match  and give no other. This is because I am parsing the text into a data-frame and it parses the three groups

Comment: So you want two groups? Remove the inner parantheses in the lookbehind.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for you to make it this complicated. Just use something like

```regex
Start: (\d+)E, (\d+)N
```

or

```regex
\b\d+(?=[EN]\b)
```

if you need to match each bit separately.

Your expression `(?=(art\:\s\s*))(?=[,])*(.*[0-9]*)` has several problems besides the ones already mentioned: 1) your first and second lookahead match at different locations, 2) your second lookahead is quantified, which, in 25 years, I have never seen someone do, so kudos. ;), 3) your capturing group matches about anything, including any line or the empty string.

Comment: What if all I wanted is a regex to match the relevant text as group 1 match  and give no other. This is because I am parsing the text into a data-frame and it parses the three groups

Comment: @wwnde I'm not sure what you mean. Could you give an example for the output you expect?

Comment: @wwnde Something as simple as `Start: (\d+)E|, (\d+)N` might do, if you don't care about what the match part looks like. This works because the capturing group is the first in both parts of the alternation.

Comment: @wwnde Or you could use a variation of my second expression and save yourself the lookahead since you are using a capturing group: `\b(\d+)[EN]\b`.

Comment: Thanks, this does it for me     x.str.extract('(?<=\D\s)*(\d+)N')

Comment: @wwnde You can reduce your expression to `\b(\d+)N`. A quantifier following a lookbehind assertion like `(?<=\D\s)*` serves no purpose and the lookbehind itself only increases the work the regex engine has to do to arrive at the exact same match in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You match the whole part after it because you use `.*` which will match until the end of the line.

Note that this part `[0-9]*` at the end of the pattern does not match because it is optional and the preceding `.*` already matches until the end of the string.

You could get the match without any lookarounds:

```
(art:\s)(\d+)[^,]+,\s(\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DDR0O5/1)

---

If you want the matches only, you could make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)

```
(?<=\bStart:(?:\s+\d+[A-Z],)* )\d+(?=[A-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I20hPm/1) (For example only, using a different engine) | [Python demo](https://rextester.com/FMHV60615)